# "Custom" validation for plugin settings page

Tags: plugin-development, datetime, validation

I have a plugin that has a few settings. One of which is a start date and and end date. Everything is set up and working fine. I'd like to validate the start/end dates a a bit though.

I am able to use `compare` to check that the end isn't before the start, but I'd also like to check that the start (or end) isn't in the past as well.

[Using this awesome page on validation](https://experiencehq.net/blog/the-definitive-guide-to-validation-in-craft-part-3-attribute-rules) I've seen how to set custom validation via `rules`. But, since I'm in a settings file, I'm not exactly sure how this translates over.

**MyPlugin.php**

```
defineSettings(){
    return array(
        'myStartDate' => array(
             AttributeType::DateTime,
             'required': true,
             'compare': '<= myEndDate'
         ),
         'myEndDate' => array(
             AttributeType::DateTime,
             'required': true,
             'compare': '>= myStartDate'
         ),
    )
}
```

What I think I'm trying to get is something like this:

```
....
'myStartDate' => array(
     AttributeType::DateTime,
     'required': true,
     'something': array(
          'rule': myValidation,
          'message': 'The start date can not be after the finish date.'
      ) 
 )
....

function myValidation() {
    // Do something here
}
```

Or, maybe I'm way off.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're on the right track. You could create a custom validator, [as detailed here](https://experiencehq.net/blog/the-definitive-guide-to-validation-in-craft-part-5-custom-validators).

```php
<?php namespace Craft;

use Carbon\Carbon;

class MyPlugin_ExampleModel extends BaseModel
{
    protected function defineAttributes()
    {
        return [
            'startDate' => [
                'type'     => AttributeType::DateTime,
                'required' => true,
                'compare'  => '<= endDate',
            ],
            'endDate' => [
                'type'     => AttributeType::DateTime,
                'required' => true,
                'compare'  => '>= startDate',
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = parent::rules();

        $rules[] = ['startDate', 'validateFutureDate'];
        $rules[] = ['endDate', 'validateFutureDate'];

        return $rules;
    }

    public function validateFutureDate($attribute)
    {
        $value = $this->$attribute;

        if ($value && Carbon::now()->gte($value)) {
            $message = Craft::t("Date must be in the future");
            $this->addError($attribute, $message);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also extract the validation into a separate class, which would make it easier to test (details are in the aforementioned article).

### Caveats and disclaimers

This code is completely untested. In particular, I'm not sure whether the date comparison will work with the attribute value as-is. You'll probably also want to check what happens to the custom validation if the value contains an invalid date-time string.